# Python how to store pixels in a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I meet such an issue:
I want to store a number of 2-D pixels like [2,3], [4,5], and [7,9] into a set
like ([2,3], [4,5], [7,9]). So that we know if a pixel is processed.

My code is like:

```
stack = ()
pixel = [2, 3]
stack = stack+(pixel)
pixel = [4, 5]
stack = stack+(pixel)
# I want stack to be ([2,3],[4,5])
if [4,5] in stack:
    pass
else:
    process this pixel
```

It shows an error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple:
> line 3:stack = stack+(pixel)

Can anyone help to solve this issue to store [x,y] in a set? like ([x1,y1], [x2,y2], ... [xn, yn])

Comment: To make a 1-tuple, you need to put an extra comma at the end, e.g. `(pixel,)`. Otherwise, it just assumes you're using parentheses for order of operations rather than for denoting a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuple always needs a comma even if you do not want to store more than two things:

```
stack = stack+(pixel,)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things going on here:

First of all, `stack = ()` creates a tuple:

```
a = ()
print(type(a))
```

results in:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

Note that a `tuple` allows duplicate elements, while a `set`'s elements are distinct.

In addition, you can't add a list to a set because lists are mutable, meaning that you can change the contents of the list after adding it to the set.

You can however add tuples to the set as tuples are imutable:

```
a = set()
pixel = (2, 3)
a.add(pixel)
pixel = (4, 5)
a.add(pixel)
print(a)
```

results in:

```
{(2, 3), (4, 5)}
```

Comment: The contents of the tuple `([1], [2])` can be changed.

Comment: @KellyBundy Right, immutable objects can contain mutable types. I changed my answer to be more percise. Thanks!

Comment: You can't add my tuple to a set, so it still sounds odd, but I guess it's ok given the context.

Comment: @KellyBundy In the question lawrance mentioned that the elements should be in a set. In the given context where the elements are immutable, I don't see an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote almost everything right. You forgot to add the comma to the tuple. A comma always goes after the tuple `,` . The comma is required otherwise Python would treat the single tuple as any string.

```
stack = ()
pixel = [2, 3]
stack = stack+(pixel,)
pixel = [4, 5]
stack = stack+(pixel,)
# I want stack to be ([2,3],[4,5])
if [4,5] in stack:
    pass
else:
    process this pixel
```

Comment: @lawrance  I think my answer was more comprehensive, but ok, no problem. Glad you solved :) The others also responded very well :)

Comment: @Kelly Bundy  True haha, sorry. I'm focusing more on the theoretical writing part. Now I have corrected, thanks :)